# Font is very ugly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, graphics, fonts

I'm drawing a string with the folowing code:

```
public Image DrawString(String lString)
{
    Image lImage = new Bitmap(128, 128);
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, lImage.Width, lImage.Height);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(lImage);
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;

    drawFormat = new StringFormat();
    drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    drawFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    Font font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular);
    font = FindBestFitFont(g, lString, font, rec.Size); 
    g.DrawString(lString, font, Brushes.Red, rec, drawFormat);

    return lImage;
}
```

The font looks very ugly even when i use:

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
```

Is there a way to make the font more smooth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

instead.

Comment: @Mehrdad you wouldn't want ClearType if this was destined for print

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried AntiAliasing or ClearType?

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
```

Comment: He draws a 128x128 pixel image, don't think it's for printing