# How to draw solid strings to a bitmap

Tags: c#, fonts, gdi+

The following code

```
var fnt = new Font("Consolas", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
var bmp = new Bitmap(24, 24);

using (var grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    var size = grp.MeasureString(shortName, fnt, new SizeF(24, 24),
         new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap |
                   StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox));
    grp.TranslateTransform(0, (bmp.Height - size.Height) / 2);
    grp.DrawString("DW", fnt, Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x33, 0x66, 0x33), 
         new RectangleF(0, 0, 24, 24),
        new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback | 
            StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox));
    grp.TranslateTransform(0, (size.Height - bmp.Height) / 2);
}
bmp.Save(string.Format("d:\\out-{0}.bmp", shortName));
```

gives output looks like[image], which does not look good (when magnified you can see black spots in border). If change the brush above to `Brushes.Black` we get [image] which is better but it is too bold (note I set the font style to "regular").

However I can achieve something like[image] manually, which is clear and thin. That one was created using GIMP, with the same font family, font size, and color on a transparent canvas.

So I wonder how I can do the same thing with GDI+ programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicate?? [Font is very ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723788/font-is-very-ugly)

```
grp.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```